# Webmatrix showing blank page

Tags: php, mysql, webmatrix

I am new to php! And i have to create a site. So i wrote the code in HTML, downloaded webmatrix, created a MySql database and inserted the code for DB connection in the php file. But when i run the php page, it shows a blank page. It works fine if I remove the code for database connection.
Here is my connection code:

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect(localhost;rjitdbUy5k1;******;rjitdb);
if(!$conn)
{
die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
}
echo
'Connected successfully';mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

[image]

The Request log displays an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer!
I missed out the 
`mysql_select_db(DBNAME)`
string.